# Wrong media type in @ExceptionHandler

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a rest controller with an endpoint for a download.
The endpoint can download a resource/entity, if it doesn't exist an error will be thrown.

The endpoint produces

`application/octet-stream` --> download

`application/json` --> error

Example

```
@RestController
public class ResourceController {

   @GetMapping( value = "/{id}", produces = { "application/json", "application/octet-stream" } )
   public ResponseEntity<Resource> download( @PathVariable final int id ) {
      if ( id % 2 == 0 ) {
         throw new EntityNotFoundException();
      }
      return ResponseEntity.ok( new ClassPathResource( "application.properties" ) );
   }

}
```

The ExceptionHandler

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ResponseExceptionHandler {

   @ExceptionHandler( EntityNotFoundException.class )
   public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleEntityNotFoundException( final HttpServletRequest request,
         final EntityNotFoundException e ) {
      return notFound( e );
   }

   protected ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> notFound(
         final Throwable e ) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>( new ErrorResponse().error( e.getMessage() ), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND );
   }
}
```

If the client uses the accept header `/*/` every works fine. Download works and if the entity is not existing an error is shown.

If the client uses the accept header `application/octet-stream` and the entity is existing the ExceptionHandler is not working cause of wrong media type and the service return a 500 error code. The exception is `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`.

Stacktrace:

```
2022-10-20 13:33:39.970  WARN 75059 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure in @ExceptionHandler com.example.demo.ResponseExceptionHandler#handleEntityNotFoundException(HttpServletRequest, EntityNotFoundException)

org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:249) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:135) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:428) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:75) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:142) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1331) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1142) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1088) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
```

...

```
2022-10-20 13:33:39.972 ERROR 75059 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.example.demo.EntityNotFoundException: Not found] with root cause

com.example.demo.EntityNotFoundException: Not found
    at com.example.demo.ResourceController.download(ResourceController.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
```

How can I solve this?
Another exception handler for HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException didn't work.

EDIT: Here is a small example
https://github.com/MelleD/wrong-media-type-exception-handler-example

Start and try: http://localhost:8080/2
with accept header "application/octet-stream")

[image]

Comment: Well I think you are not even throwing EntityNotFoundException at this point.  Have you debugged to see if you are going inside the controller download() method when using `application/octet-stream`because it might not be going due to the difference in request types

Comment: What values have you specified for `consumes/produces` into your controller method `@RequestMapping`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I added a small runnable example. Maybe then it's clearer

Comment: You seem to be trying to solve a follow-on problem that might not need to be solved. That is, if the method can return two different Content-types, a client calling and saying it will only accept one of them would be a client that can't reliably make that call. So, I'd say focusing on handling that case in some non-default way is not worth the effort.

Comment: Yes I know the issue but IMHO is 500 with a empty error message not the best response. I would like to change this…

Comment: Do you solve the issue?